# Chrome remote-debugging-port not work passing by ssh > https

Tags: nginx, ssh, https, google-chrome-devtools

With Chromium (In an electron app)

I need to use the [remote-debugging-port](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) on public IP. For security reasons Chrome will not allow access from another hostname except 'localhost'.

To solve it I use ssh tunnel with this command:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:4101:localhost:4100 localhost -N
```

​
It work fine and I can acces it with http://:4101/. But now I want to use it over https.

For that, I try to use Nginx because I already use it for HTTPS:

```
  server {
      listen 4101 ssl;
      proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
      proxy_send_timeout 7d;
      proxy_read_timeout 7d;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
      charset   utf-8;
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
      location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4100/;
      }
  }
```

But I get this error:

> 2018/08/28 16:28:22 [error] 4234#4234: *3 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   10.0.19.235, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4100/favicon.ico", host: "myDomain.local:4101",
>   referrer: "https://myDomain.local:4101/"

​
I try to change this headers with different value like $server_addr, $remote_addr, "localhost", 127.0.0.1, without result:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP    $server_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-for $server_addr;
```

I think it s necessary to change some header to let think the remote console that we are from localhost but I don't know which one even after reading the Nginx doc.

Do you have any suggestions?